# PopItem in dictionary returns Last inserted pair for 3.7 onwards. How is it as dictionary is unordered

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

[popitem()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=popitem#dict.popitem) in dictionary guarantee to return last inserted pair for 3.7 and onward. Dictionary is unordered type. So, how dictionary is able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer unordered starting 3.6 (implementation detail) and guaranteed as of 3.7. So naturally methods that are based on order have predictable results now.

See [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)